# Passing location coordinates to google maps as variable

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Anyone know why this will work:

```
var wickedLocation =  new google.maps.LatLng(44.767778, -93.2775);
```

But this won't:

```
var wickedCoords = "44.767778, -93.2775";
var wickedLocation =  new google.maps.LatLng(wickedCoords);
```

I tried passing the latitude and longitude as separate variables and that didn't do the trick either. How can I pass the coordinates successfully as a variable? Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In this example, you are passing two distinct numerical values into a constructor and then assigning the newly created object to wickedLocation:

```
var wickedLocation =  new google.maps.LatLng(44.767778, -93.2775);
```

In this example, you're passing a single string value into a constructor that requires two distinct numerical coordinates:

```
var wickedCoords = "44.767778, -93.2775";
var wickedLocation =  new google.maps.LatLng(wickedCoords);
```

The data types are both completely different.

With that said, if you want to represent a coordinate as a single object, you can do so like this:

```
var myHome = { "lat" : "44.767778" , "long" : "-93.2775" };

var yourHome = { "lat" : "23,454545" , "long" : "-92.12121" };
```

Then when you need to create the coords object from Google, you can pass the data in as individual arguments derived from a single object:

```
var wickedLocation =  new google.maps.LatLng( myHome.lat, myHome.long );
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. What data type would you use to pass the the coordinates? An array?

Comment: An array would likely have the same problem. An array would be a single argument passed into a constructor that requires 2 arguments.

Comment: @coryetzkorn - I updated my answer with some more information that may be helpful. You can represent a coordinate as an object with 2 properties, then pass the individual properties in as individual arguments.

Answer (score 7):

If you are getting the coordinates as a string, in the format you showed in your example, you could do this:

```
var b=wickedCoords.split(",");
var wickedLocation=new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(b[0]), parseFloat(b[1]));
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use strings to define the coordinates, but you need two (one for each parameter) not one.

```
wickedLat = '44.767778';
wickedLon = '-93.2775';
wickedLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(wickedLat, wickedLon);
```

If not either use floats directly or parse your strings into floats with `parseFloat()`

Comment: I just tested this as best I could and it looks like it would work. It doesn't throw any errors, and the resulting objects from both params as strings and params as numbers are the same. It's not in the documentation, so there's no guarantee this would continue to work. Still, I'd +1, but I'm out of votes for the day :)