# google maps - wrong (different) routes directions

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I try to get the instructions of a route direction from two points, but the route appears different when I give the coordinates through the source code (coorect route), than when the function gets them from the textbox. I want you to know that I am interested in finding the route only by the coordinates and not by the address

Thank you in advance

form source code (correct route) - http://www.touchsmart.gr/stackoverflow_map/route_from_variable.html

from textbox (wrong route) - http://www.touchsmart.gr/stackoverflow_map/route_from_text.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are two different things.  The correct route is passing in google.map.LatLng objects, the incorrect route is not.  To use geographic coordinates you need to pass in google.map.LatLng objects, otherwise the coordinates get geocoded.

```
destination LatLng|string   Location of destination. This can be specified as either a string to be geocoded or a LatLng. Required.
origin  LatLng|string   Location of origin. This can be specified as either a string to be geocoded or a LatLng. Required.
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10676828/passing-location-coordinates-to-google-maps-as-variable) for how to convert a comma separated string to a google.maps.LatLng object.